# handsontable: inserting data using ajax

Tags: jquery, json, handsontable

I can't find the right way for inserting data in a handsontable
table using $.ajax function with jquery.
Is there any helpfull tutorial or example on this?

Many,many thanks!!

---

Thanks for the example, but I'm not capable of pushing a PHP array to handsontable via json
(using PHP::json_encode()).
I tried a lot, but finally it didn't work...

For example: I got a few arrays with rows:

```
<?php
        $row1 = array(1=>"value1",
        2=>"value2",
        3=>"value3",
        4=>"value4",
        5=>"value5");

    $row2 = array(1=>"value1",
        2=>"value2",
        3=>"value3",
        4=>"value4",
        5=>"value5");

    $row3 = .......
```

so I tried:

```
$data = array($row1,$row2,$row...);
echo json_encode($data);
```

but it doesn't work at all...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7):

The below example shows how to load and save data using $.ajax and Handsontable:

```
var first = true;
$("#example6grid").handsontable({
  rows: 8,
  cols: 8,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  minSpareCols: 1,
  minSpareRows: 1,
  contextMenu: true,
  onChange: function (change) {
    if (first) {
      first = false;
      return; //don't save this change
    }
    $.ajax({ //saves changes from Handsontable
      url: "save.php",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      data: {"data": $("#example6grid").handsontable('getData')}, //returns full array of grid data
      //data: change, //contains only information about changed cells
      success: function (data) {
        console.log("saved", data);
      },
      error: function (data) {
        console.log("error", data);
      }
    });
  }
});

$.ajax({ //loads data to Handsontable
  url: 'source.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(res){
    $("#example6grid").handsontable("loadData", res.data);
  }
});
```

The code above assumes that `<div id="example6grid" class="dataTable"></div>` exists, and that file `source.json` contains the following JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
  ]
}
```

Comment: I added a proper Load & Save example to the demo page: http://handsontable.com/#example9 – warpech Jul 17 at 12:06

Comment: Link is dead. [Here's](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.3.4/tutorial-load-and-save.html) another example from the docs.